How to remove or increase Max Recursion Depth in Unity?
So I'm creating a game similar to jetpack joyride where bullets fire downwards while "jump" is held. I get the following issue in the console after I play for a short amount of time:

"StackOverflowException: Max recursion depth of 100 has been exceeded. Consider increasing 'Recursion.defaultMaxDepth'."

I'm guessing this is because the amount of bullets in the scene has exceeded 100, but I'm not sure how to remove this limit. The bullets get destroyed after a collision, and I like the current rate of fire.
Visual script for my player jump function that spawns in bullets every frame while jump is held:

Visual script showing the script after collision:

Any help will be greatly appreciated, and also any tips on how to improve my visual scripting!

It shouldn't matter how many bullets you have.   Recursion is when something calls itself. While im on my phone so have tiny screen i dont think i saw any recusion here.

Your problem may be in the bullet script but cant tell without seen it

Do bullets collide with themselves or each other?

Your error doesn't have anything to do with the number of bullets you have on screen but how many times a function is called within itself. Typically, this is called when a function is calling itself on repeat without breaking out at any point. To so programmatically:
void functionName()
{
    // Do Something
    functionName()
}

Would end up throwing the same error. Most code compilers have a limit to how many times a piece of code can call itself before it throws this error, in your case its saying its 100. So if you used my code above (ignoring it isn't visual), it would throw the error when it calls itself for the 100th time.
Ideally, you don't want to be removing the limit as it could cause problems later on. You want to find where your code is being recursive and check that it isn't something that can quickly spiral out of control. Its a little hard to read in your screenshots, but I can't see any instances of recursion. Its worth checking some of your other scripts to see if there's anything elsewhere that might be repeatedly calling itself.
